# Google Play Console signing error/invalid signature after rebuilding react-native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, zipalign

Our team decided to upgrade our react-native version from 0.59.x to 0.61.5. We have so many difficulty upgrading it so we decide to start a new repo from fresh (npx react-native init appName) and copy over our code.

After we make sure the app are running both on Android and ios simulator. We use the same scripts to build the .aab file and upload to Google Play Console. But Google Play Console won't let us. This is the error message shown:

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about
> signing). Error from apksigner:

There is no other error message after "apksigner:" so I am pretty sure it is a different problem than other similar questions on stack overflow.

I am also sure that we are using the same keystore file

Below is how we build our .aab file

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
cd $REPO_PATH/android
./gradlew bundleRelease
cd ..

# sign the aab
jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/my-release-key.keystore $REPO_PATH/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab traytAndroidKey

# zipalign the aab and output it to another file 
$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign -f -v 4 $REPO_PATH/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab $REPO_PATH/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release-signed-aligned-$VERSION_CODE.aab
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are uploading an AAB and not an APK.
AABs don't need to be zip-aligned.
Try only signing with jarsigner.

Also, try verifying the signature with jarsigner too.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. So after react-native 0.60 it doesn't need to be zipalign anymore? Because zipalign didn't cause any problem on 0.59.x even when I use .aab file.

Comment: I'm not sure honestly what's the root cause. Only APKs require zip alignment, AABs never needed zip-alignment.